# Google OAuth 2 authorization - swapping code for token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth 2 to get access to Google APIs. I follow [this](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) guide, using server-side scenario.

I have no problem with getting the code, server redirects to localhost (which is the only server allowed in redirect URIs for now). 
To achieve this, I go to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=whatever.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code` page.

Then, I tried using `curl` (as in guide) to test, if Google's server responds with access token. However, it seems to fail very hard. Only response I can get is `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. I'm sure I provide everything Google wants me to provide - code, client ID, client secret, redirect URI (localhost) and `grant_type=authorization_code`.

Whole `curl` command line is:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "code=<code>&client_id=whatever.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=<won't tell!>&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

Am I missing something? How can I exchange code for access token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you `urlencode` your client secret and redirect url?  That works for me.

Should be `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost` instead of `https://localhost`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error until I realized that I was trying to connect with a client ID which I created for iOS. So for me the solution was to create a new API key-secret pair on the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) with the platform set to "other".

Now I'm getting other errors but that's another story. ;)

Comment: Brilliant.  It may be that newer versions of the GData code work when you use the iOS setting.

Comment: That was exactly the solution to my problem when testing on the simulator... This answer shortened my search, thank you Lvsti!

Answer (score 1):

Happens when you use wrong Client secret. Make sure you are using correct Client secret from Google API console. I was using Email address since API console displays the information in the following order:

1. **Client ID**
2. Email address
3. **Client secret**