# Google oauth token giving 405 error

Tags: coldfusion, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-405

I am trying to post using below Code. I expect it to return token but its returning **error 405 Method Not Allowed**.

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" >
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="code" value="#url.CODE#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="client_id" value="458381219741.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="client_secret" value="XXXXXXX">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="redirect_uri" value="http://console.mbwebportal.com/oauth2callback">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
</cfhttp>
```

The above code is on  http://console.mbwebportal.com/oauth2callback and it gets the Code in url after user allows access to the application.

Please help!!

Comment: shouldn't you be using httpS protocol in your request? from Google's https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer page: "This request is an HTTPs post, and includes the following parameters..."

Comment: no https give some other error(like page not found). It has to be HTTP 1.1 request as per google documentation, which automatically calls https address. Try pasting http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token in your browser, you will see it converts to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: key was to use cfhttpparam type '**body**'.
As per livedocs "body: specifies the body of the HTTP request. ColdFusion does not automatically set a content-type header or URL encode the body contents. To specify the content-type, use a separate cfhttp tag with type=header. "

Below code is returning me access token now :)

```
<cfset client_id = "458381219741.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<cfset client_secret = "**********">
<cfset callback = "http://console.mbwebportal.com/oauth2callback">

<cfset postBody = "code=" & UrlEncodedFormat(url.code) & "&">
<cfset postBody = postBody & "client_id=" & UrlEncodedFormat(client_id) & "&">
<cfset postBody = postBody & "client_secret=" & UrlEncodedFormat(client_secret) & "&">
<cfset postBody = postBody & "redirect_uri=" & UrlEncodedFormat(callback) & "&">
<cfset postBody = postBody & "grant_type=authorization_code">
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="header" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#postBody#">
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar post here [Google OAuth 2 authorization - swapping code for token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668664/google-oauth-2-authorization-swapping-code-for-token).  The answer for them was to url encode the client secret key and redirect uri.  In ColdFusion you can use the `URLEncodedFormat()` function to do that for you.

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" >
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="code" value="#url.CODE#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="client_id" value="458381219741.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="client_secret" value="#URLEncodedFormat(XXXXXXX)#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="redirect_uri" value="#URLEncodedFormat("http://console.mbwebportal.com/oauth2callback")#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
</cfhttp>
```

And please validate your `url.CODE` value before using it as anything can be passed in the URL.

Comment: It didn't worked same problem. Also if I just do cfhttp with 1 cfhttpparam, it gives similar error. So far I can url http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token is not even looking at the parameters sent. It just don't like the way data is post :(