# Why does OAuth2 authentication work on home machine but not on a server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, eol

I'm struggling to get OAuth2 authorisation to work on a script I'm working on when I run it on an EC2 Linux server instance (running Ubuntu 13.04). The relevant snippet is:

```
with open('creds.txt') as f:
    creds = {}
    for line in f:
        creds[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1].rstrip('\n')

self.client_id = creds['client_id']
self.client_secret = creds['client_secret']
self.username = creds['username']
self.password = creds['password'])

token_response = requests.post(
    "https://example.com/oauth2/access_token/", 
    data={
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": self.client_id,
        "client_secret": self.client_secret,
        "username": self.username,
        "password": self.password,
        "scope": "read+write"}).json()
```

It runs fine on my home computer (running Windows 7), just not when I try and run it remotely where I get: `{u'error': u'invalid_client'}`.

I've tried setting up a new client ID and secret and still get the same response.

- Why does it work differently on a remote server to on my own machine?
- <strike>Does it matter on which machine the application was created (see comment)?</strike> - I eliminated this possibility by successfully authenticating using `CURL` in both environments.

The only thing I can think of now is that perhaps the requests library handles the POST request differently on Ubuntu. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267728/1706564) seems like it might be relevant as it suggests that the client ID cares what OS it was generated on. I can't find anything to confirm that in [the docs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the first thing I should have thought of when there's a difference between Nix and Windows environments:

***Always** check the EOL chars!*

The problem was that when grabbing the username, password, etc. from my credentials file, I was stripping the newline character using `string.rstrip('\n')`, so in the Unix environment that was leaving an `\r` carriage return character behind which was then being passed as part of the `POST` request.

The [simple and correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275025/1706564) which works in both environments is to use `string.rstrip()` which strips all trailing whitespace and end of line chars.